# Unable to uninstall Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.100 from Mac

Tags: asp.net-core

I am unable to uninstall the Package Microsoft.NETCore.App version 3.1.100 from my Mac OS. help? The steps on the Microsoft page do not work on the terminal. Help?

Comment: Refer this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=macos

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is the place to get answers to your programming / coding issues

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had to change the commands provided in the Microsoft documentation. Thanks!